# restkit, map object with specific variabes

Tags: ios, json, serialization, mapping, restkit

I am adding an `attributesMappingsDictionary` to my `RKEntityMapping` object. This maps keys to model values, where it will get JSON and map my model object to the associated keys I told it about

But what about circumstances where the JSON will not actually contain the proper value in its response? How do I manually set one variable to always equal a certain string that I create under certain conditions?

How do I set `additionalLocalVariable: true`  when I am creating and caching the `RKEntityMapping` or after I get the network response?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a default value in the model so all new objects will have that value until it's replaced. Or you can use KVC validation to update the object during mapping. Or you can update the objects in the completion block and then resave the context.